# Is there a word for the spatial equivalent of contemporary?

Tags: single-word-requests

From [dictionary.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporary)

> contemporary: happening, existing, living, or coming into being during the same
> period of time

I'm looking for something that means existing in the same place, but not necessarily in the same time.

"Neighboring" is close, but it seems to imply both spatial proximity and temporal overlap.

## sample sentence.

Thomas Edison and Nikola Tesla are contemporary historical, while
Charles de Gaulle and Joan of Arc are ______ historical figures.

Comment: The aequivalent construction would be something like *collocational* (Latin) or *syntopical* (Greek).

Comment: Thomas Edison and Nikola Tesla share a historical period, while Charles de Gaulle and Joan of Arc share a geographical (or cultural) context.

Comment: @Cerberus you should make this an answer.

Comment: **Coeval** works as well as contemporary. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=coeval&t=ffsb&ia=definition As does **cotemporal** https://www.definitions.net/definition/cotemporal **cospatial** http://www.yourdictionary.com/cospatial sort of fills in for what your asking for but is *awk*.  Other than "French", I'm sure there's a word that means exactly what you want. It's been too long though. Tray asking over at Math stack. They should know.

Comment: @aparente001: Done.

Comment: @guenthmonstr: Done.

Comment: @aparente001: Oops! I must have mislicked.

Comment: ... are ***French*** historical figures....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the word "compatriot" or "national" along with historical figures in your example.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/compatriot

Possibly would "dimensional", as a special alternative, or "geographic" be the meaning you are seeking?

Comment: This is a good answer, and fills in the bank pretty well. But I was hoping for a more general term. One that would work even if the two people didn't necessarily share a nation, but a any arbitrary place (which makes me think I should edit my sentence).

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  In that case, I would offer "dimensional" as a special alternative, or "geographic" depending on the flavor of meaning you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

The aequivalent construction would be something like **collocational** (Latin) "of the same place" or **syntopical** (Greek) "(same)". But I think the other answer's *compatriot* is preferable if indeed it is about the same country or perhaps city.

Comment: I think the correct term would be _syntopic_ (from _topos_ "place"),though I've only heard it in a biological sense.From [yourdictionary (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20230223023233/https://www.yourdictionary.com/syntopical)), "_Syntopical_ Definition-Referring to a type of analysis in which different works are compared and contrasted,"and "Origin of _Syntopical_ -Coined by Mortimer Adler in 'How to Read a Book'. Derived from the term Syntopicon®,a two-volume topical guide published as part of the Great Books of the Western World series." That would be from _Ta Topika_ (commonplace).

Comment: @bballdave025: Hmm, well, both would be proper formations.

Comment: I'm glad to learn my new thing for the day, @Cerberus_-_Reinstate_Monica.